# Django syncdb AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: mysql, database, django, models, syncdb

Have not been able to find a solution for this.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    prod_price = models.FloatField()
    prod_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    prod_description = models.TextField()
    prod_attributes = models.TextField()
    prod_ingredients = models.TextField()
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'MyApp',
```

This is the error that's thrown:

> Creating tables ...
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
>     File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>     File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in handle
>       return self.handle_noargs(**options)
>     File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 91, in handle_noargs
>       sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, self.style, seen_models)
>     File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\creation.py", line 82, in sql_create_model
>       style.SQL_TABLE(qn(opts.db_table)) + ' (']
>     File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 244, in quote_name
>       if name.startswith("`") and name.endswith("`"):
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

So the key part:
**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'**

Anybody have any ideas as to why I'm getting this error? I've tried alot of different things and it just wont work even thou it creates the other tables successfully it just won't create my model classes. I am using a mysql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback suggests that you may have used the `db_table` option incorrectly. It should be a string, not a list. Please check your usage, and update your question with more code if you are not sure.

Comment: How could I not see that. As you say i was using the db_table option incorrectly. I changed it to class Meta: db_table = u'Products' Thanks Alot Man